# getting null pointer exception when clicking other jtable cell

Tags: jtable, jcombobox

I used a customized JComboBox as a cell editor for my Jtable. My problem is when I choose nothing from the combo box and click other cell, I get a null pointer exception. But when I select something from the combobox and click other cell, I do not get an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it. i was creating objects using default constructor which gives me an object with its properties set to null. thus the error on jtable update.